# How to go to previous step when user press NO in the console

Tags: install4j

In my application, I am asking the user to enter the machine name after that I am displaying the machine name and ask the user to confirm whether the name is ok if he presses no I need to ask him to enter the name again. If he presses Yes  he can continue to next step

Comment: It works the same as in GUI mode, by returning `false` in the "Validation` script property of the screen.

Comment: I don't need this in the GUI I need it only in console mode

Comment: Yes, I just meant that there is no difference in how you do it for console mode.

Comment: I want to repeat only one step in that screen, not all the steps

Comment: Then you have to make a separate screen for console mode only (Condition expression `context.isConsole()`) or use the "Console handler" form component where you are totally flexible.